# Float within media query not working on input after display: block

Tags: css, css-float

With the below code the input should be on the same line as the text when the viewport is larger than 320px. It works as expected on the first page load (when media query is activated), but after the viewport is resized below 320px the `float: left` will not work anymore, even if the viewport is enlarged again.

Expected result when viewport >= 320px

[image: Input is floated left of text]

After resizing viewport < 320px

[image: Input is below text]

Result when viewport is resized back to  >= 320px

[image: Input is below text]

This behaviour is only exhibited when the following conditions are satisfied:

- Browser is Google Chrome
- Floated element is an `input` (any type)
- `float` rule is within a media query
- Floated element defaults to `display: block` with no media query applied
- `float` rule is disabled (either by resizing the viewport or within dev tools) then enabled again

I am using Chrome 41.0.2272.101 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 14.04. The behaviour is not exhibited in Firefox 38.0 on the same platform. I have not tested any other browsers.

```css
.text {
  display: inline-block;
}
input {
  display: block;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  input {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Text</div>
<input type="text">
```

You can try it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/ws2guLrq/1/

Comment: This looks like a bug in Chrome to me. But rest assured that not many people keep resizing their browser windows all the time, so it's not that big an issue.

Comment: sdcr: Thanks, but that works because `input` defaults to `display: inline-block`, I need it to be `display: block`.

Comment: I don't really need a workaround, this is on an admin login page which will rarely be that small and even more rarely resized.

Comment: It's only a block element so it will display below the previous two elements which are inline-block. I don't want 100% width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you are looking for, make use of `max-width` instead and switch the arguments around.

```
.text {
    display: inline-block;
}
input {
    float: left;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 319px) {
    input {
        float: none;
    }
}
```

If I understood your question correctly then this is what you want, I have only tested this in Chrome.

Comment: Yeah that's a good simple solution, I think you meant `float: none`, not `display: block` though. Also `max-width: 319px`. If you want to make those changes I'll accept it.